# Pygame Not Responding

Tags: python, user-interface, pygame

I'm learning pygame, and I just entered a few basic lines to try to move a ball across my window, but after displaying the image, the window will just freeze.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
ball = pygame.image.load("ball.png").convert()
ball_rect = ball.get_rect()
white = (255,255,255)


frames = 100


for x in range(frames):
    screen.blit(ball, ball_rect) # display player
    ball_rect.move(2, 2) # move player
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    screen.fill(white) # erase player
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window is not freezing, it's just refreshing the same image at the same place during the 10 seconds you have set.

This is mostly caused by the method used to move the image, you should use `move_ip` instead of `move` as a quick fix ([doc](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move_ip)).

Another change you can do is replace the for loop by a while, to let the player quit when he wants :

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
ball = pygame.image.load("ball.png").convert()
ball_rect = ball.get_rect()
white = (255,255,255)


looping = True
while looping:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if(event.type is pygame.QUIT):
            looping = False    

    screen.fill(white) # erase player            

    screen.blit(ball, ball_rect) # display player
    ball_rect.move_ip(2, 2) # move player
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(10)  # to keep the same FPS, better increase  !
    # Thanks skrx !
```

Comment: Better instantiate a [clock](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) `clock = pygame.time.Clock()` and then call `clock.tick(desired_frame_rate)` each frame to limit the frame rate. `pygame.time.delay` makes games unresponsive.